# language validation in Oracle Apex 5.1.4

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

how to validate on an item in Oracle Apex 5.1.4, 
I want the input value in a certain language, and not to accept other languages

Comment: That's likely not practical in any framework.  I suppose if you got a dictionary of every word that you want to consider valid in that language, you could compare the input and reject anything that has a word that doesn't match.  Of course, that will require the user to correct any spelling errors and any lingo that isn't in the dictionary (specialized words and abbreviations, text speak, etc.).  That seems unlikely to be particularly user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Character Set at most. 
If your goal is to prevent the user from entering the Cyrillic alphabet for example.

- e.g. UTF-8, Windows 1250 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language) to detect the language of any string. As long as you're registered to use the API you may have your validation to make an HTTP request and get which language the user has entered.